# How to show only important file in project explorer in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt

After evaluating multiple IDE's for cross platform C++ development (Code blocks, CLion, CodeLite, QTCreator, KDevelop, NetBeans) I thought of sticking to eclipse CDT as it was the only one that gave a good user experience apart from CLion, UNTIL I wanted to filter out all unwanted files that are shown in the project explorer. I know I can filter them out using project properties by adding multiple inclusions and exclusions, but is there a simpler way like editing a text file where I specify a comma separated list of inclusions and exclusions? And more importantly, how do I do that for all projects in the work space? The current GUI based way takes time, confusing and I dont know how to do that for all projects. After-all, users of Eclipse CDT are developers and they really dont need a dialog based work-flow to do this.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but perhaps [Mylyn](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)'s task-focused interface can do what you want (basically, select a subset of files that are relevant to your work and only show those)?

Comment: I surely can try that out. Thanks for sharing.